# How to assign single class to multiple variables in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any way to assign a class to multiple variables in JQuery ?

```
    let x = $('#FirstId'),
        y = $('#SecondId');
```

I want to Add a class to both variables in a single statement ,something like this :

```
    (x,y).addClass('Something');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array and loop through each item in that array

```js
let x = $('#FirstId'), y = $('#SecondId');

// Here you create an array with both variables and loop through that variable
[x, y].forEach(item => item.addClass('blue'));
```

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="FirstId">First Item</p>
<p id="SecondId">First Item</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add directly from the ids like:

```
$("#FirstId, #SecondId").addClass('Something');
```

You can [read](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) more in the link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my real selectors are not that simple . This code is just for example. I need to work with variables .

Comment: You can cast variable to string like that: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/convert+var+to+string+jquery

Then you can join them if you need to use variables. Or you can simply create for loop. 

Other thing comes to my mind is to add a class or some attribute to tags that you want to add class and simply use that class name as a selector to add class